# Parallel lines & triangles

Tags: triangles

[image]

Two lines $GE$ and $FD$ meet in $A$. They cut each other at $45$ degrees. Both $G$ and $F$ lie on the circumcircle of square $ALBK$ such that $E$ and $D$ lie on the $KB$ and $LB$ respectively without lying on the corners of the square. I'm supposed to prove that $GF$ and $ED$ are parallel. 
1) How does one prove parallelism of lines in general?
2) $45$ degrees seems rather specific, could the same be proven with any angle? (i.e. $20$ degrees)

Comment: *Are* they parallel? Take the particular case where $D=B$; then $F=B$, too, so that (still distinct) lines $GF$ and $EB$ meet.

Comment: Yes, the are parallel. However I have no clue how to show this.

Comment: Now that you've changed the relevant angle from $30^\circ$ to $45^\circ$, yes: the lines *are* parallel. (My counterexample fails, because, when $D=B=F$, we have $G=E=K$, so that the lines are no longer distinct; their meeting at $B$ is no longer problematic. In any case, the counterexample answers your second question.)

Comment: I'm sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: This question belongs an ongoing competition! (see the translated exercises here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29448/german-contest-bundeswettbewerb-mathematik?cb=1)

Comment: I've flagged this for moderator attention.