# Parallel lines & squares

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, quadrilateral

A square $P_1P_2P_3P_4$ has points $X$ on side $P_2P_3$ and $Y$ on side $P_3P_4$ chosen such that angle $XP_1Y$ equals forty-five degrees. The lines $P_1X$ and $P_1Y$ intersect the circumcircle of the square at points $R$ and $S$, respectively.
How can one show that the lines $XY$ and $RS$ run parallel?
[image]

A geometric-algebraic solution using trigonometric addition properties is fairly straightforward and gives a solution. Yet here I´m looking for a more elegant elementary geometric solution. The intersections with the circumcircle, points $R$ and $S$ can be construed as corners of another square of equal size as the initial one using the Pythagorean theorem.
Here´s where I think a line or two or a smart angle hunt could solve it but got stuck. Any suggestion?

Comment: This question, in different words, is part of an on-going contest (see [translated questions on Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29448/german-contest-bundeswettbewerb-mathematik?cb=1)) that ends on 4 March, 2019. (Moreover, the question was [asked here previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3034992/409).) I'm flagging this question for moderator attention.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the quadrilateral *RSYX* and show that it is an isosceles trapezoid. You can show it by proving that *SY* and *RX* have the same length and *SYX* and *YXR* form the same angle.

Comment: Could you please provide some intermediate steps? Only thing I see is that angles TSO = URO = 45°

Comment: Since *P1XY* is a isosceles triangle then the angles *P1YX* and *YXP1* are the same. This implies that *SYX* and *YXR* are the same because *SYX* = 180º - *P1YX* and *YXR* = 180º - *YXP1*. Now to show that *SY* and *RX* lengths are equal just use that *SP1P3* = *RP1P3* by simmetry.

Comment: @JoseManuelSanchezCuadrado: The question has been locked for being part of [an on-going contest](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29448/german-contest-bundeswettbewerb-mathematik?cb=1). Perhaps you should delete your question, and "undelete" it after 4 March, 2019.